# Как изменить ViewController в WindowController без открытия нового окна

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, storyboard

Я хочу, чтобы ViewController с содержимым окна переключался на другой ViewController по нажатию кнопки. Но у меня получается только открыть новое окно.

Можно использовать:

```
[self presentViewControllerAsSheet:controllerNew];
```

Но тогда другой контроллер открывается поверх старого, не закрываясь. К тому же, у него анимация есть, а мне не нужна анимация.

Как правильно открыть ViewController в существующем ViewController?

В iOS проекте я делаю так:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:NO];
```

Также интересно, что такое `animator` в этой функции:

```
[self presentViewController:controllerNew animator: ];
```

Где его взять? И вообще, что это? Гуглил, гуглил, не нашёл примеров.

Comment: Ответов не будет? :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ViewController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004233-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: незнаю ваших целей, но вообще в osx все строится вокруг окон nswindow, содержащих один или несколько вьюх, и их контроллеров nswindowscontroller, контроллеры вьюх редко где используются, имеет смысл только для сложных многократноиспользуемых вьюх

Comment: Вы используете сториборды или используете классический подход с xib?

Comment: @Sega-Zero, сториборды

Comment: Если сториборды, то единственный правильный способ - переход на желаемый сегвей. [performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSeguePerforming/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) - то что доктор прописал.

Comment: @Sega-Zero, а смысл? Точно так же открывает новое окно, а не заменяет старое :).

Можно ли тогда как-то открывать новое окно, но закрывать старое. Программно.

Comment: У вас какое-то недопонимание того, как работают сториборды в OSX. Если вам нужно поведение схожее iOS (хотя это несколько неправильно), это делается тривиально, достаточно задать свой тип сегвея, в котором переопределить метод perform. Ну или использовать готовое, например [GRPushSegue](https://github.com/insidegui/GRPushSegue)

Comment: @Sega-Zero, ну что есть, то есть. 2 года кодинга на iOS дают о себе знать, GRPushSegue то что нужно, спасибо.

Comment: Можете принять мой ответ, чтобы другие также могли найти решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы иметь поведение, схожее с iOS, нужно просто переопределить работу сегвея в методе `perform`. Есть готовое решение в виде [GRPushSegue](https://github.com/insidegui/GRPushSegue).
Настоятельно рекомендую посмотреть [видео про сториборды на OSX](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#212) с WWDC, чтобы в будущем не было недопониманий о том, как правильно с ними работать. Отвыкайте от iOS подходов:)

Comment: Кстати, у меня у одного не открывается main.storyboard в проекте GRPushSegue? Вылетает xCode.

Comment: Видимо да. У меня всё работает хорошо.

Comment: А OS X у Вас какая? У меня 10.10, не обновлялся на 10.10.3.

Comment: видимо придётся обновиться:)

Comment: Обновился, теперь все гуд :).

Comment: Код немного подправил, и стало то что хотел. Содержимое animatePresentationOfViewController: изменил на:
fromViewController.view = viewController.view; И теперь то что надо, но появилась новая проблема: все норм заменяется, но когда пытаюсь уже загрузить другой контроллер, после того как перешел на этот, то выбивает ошибку: presentViewController:animator:: View '<SellingViewController: 0x6080001e3a00>''s view is not in a window/view hierarchy. Т.е. второй раз перейти на другой контроллер не получается. Почему? Эту ошибку в iOS выдет когда пытаешься открыть контроллер из viewDidLoad.

Comment: Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос с конкретным кодом, который работает неверно